# SAP UI5 Json Model Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, count, sapui5

i have the following Problem. Sorry for my bad english that way.

I want to read a jsonfile and count the Number of Persons in it.
This result i will write to an variable.This variable is connected to the TileContainer. So when i write an new entry in my Json File i want that the TileContainer number is increased to.

Here my Code from my Company.json File:

```
{
                    "mitarbeiter":  [        

                    {   "Lastname": "Mustermann",
                        "Firstname": "Max",
                        "icon": "sap-icon://globe",
                        "adress": "Essen",
                        "geschlecht": "männlich",
                        "plz": "42222",
                        "street": "Viehoferplatz 11",
                        "jobinfo": "Softwareentwickler"
                    },
                    {   "Lastname": "Fischer",
                        "Firstname": "Elke",
                        "icon": "sap-icon://globe",
                        "adress": "Hamburg",
                        "geschlecht": "weiblich",
                        "plz": "31441",
                        "street": "Am Fischmarkt 12",
                        "jobinfo": "Verwaltungsassistentin"
                    },
                    {   "Lastname": "Mustermann",
                        "Firstname": "Heike",
                        "icon": "sap-icon://globe",
                        "adress": "Essen",
                        "geschlecht": "weiblich",
                        "plz": "42222",
                        "street": "Viehoferplatz 11",
                        "jobinfo": "Vorstandsvorsitzende"
                    }

                    ]
```

}

on my controller.js

```
onInit: function() {

         this.getView().addDelegate({onBeforeShow: function(evt) {   
         if (this.direction != "back") {
             var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
             model.loadData("JsonModels/Company.json");
             alert(model.getJSON());
             var XYZ;

             var jsonModel =  
                            {
                              "Tiles":[
                                {"Tile":
                                {   id : "idModelTile1",
                                    title : "Mitarbeiter",
                                    info: "Mitarbeiterdaten",
                                    icon:"sap-icon://company-view",
                                    activeIcon:"inbox",
                                    number: XYZ,
                                    appto: "idListPage"
                                    //numberUnit: "positions"
                                    },  
                                }, ......
```

I want that the variable XYZ gets the Length Value, bevor the TileContainer is rendered. So the Number of Company-Employess is given on the Selectionscreen View.

Hope some one can help me. I make some implementations with jquery and so but nothing really work fine.

Dear,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

Since the length property of an array can be read, you could simply use

```
var XYZ = model.getProperty("/mitarbeiter/length");
```

EDIT: here's a code example for the comment I gave below

```
onInit: function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "JsonModels/Company.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            var mitarbeiterCount = data.length;
            var oTileModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oTileModel.setData({
                tiles :[{
                    tile : {   
                        id        : "idModelTile1",
                        title     : "Mitarbeiter",
                        info      : "Mitarbeiterdaten",
                        icon      :"sap-icon://company-view",
                        activeIcon:"inbox",
                        number    : mitarbeiterCount,
                        appto     : "idListPage"
                    },  
                }]
            });
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oTileModel);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Oh no, an error occurred");
        }
    });
}
```

In your view, if you now bind your tile's number property, it should automagically work:

```
var oTileTemplate = new sap.m.StandardTile({
    icon      : "{icon}",
    number    : "{number}",
    numberUnit: "mitarbeiter",
    title     : "{title}",
    info      : "{info}"
});

var oTileContainer = new sap.m.TileContainer().bindAggregation("tiles", "/", oTileTemplate);

//Etc...
```

Comment: Using the power of data binding is key to the answer here, it should take care of the async nature, as @Qualiture has indicated.

Answer (score 0):

When i add

```
 alert(model.getProperty("/mitarbeiter/length"));
```

i get the alert message "undefined"...

Comment: That is because the data is loaded asynchronous, and the property does not exist yet. 
Either set the `async` property to true https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData, or better yet, use the standard `jQuery.ajax` call and set both the XYZ variable as well as the model.setData in the ajax success handler

Comment: Problem with jQuery.ajax is that the TileContainer was rendered etc bevor the Length of this Array is called (called can be the wrong word). So the TileContainer don't show any Number :(

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you "set both the XYZ variable as well as the model.setData in the ajax success handler" because, as a colleague of mine puts it, "the databinding solves everything". I will update mu original comment with a code example.